# cabal test for not exposed modules

Tags: haskell, cabal

My situations:

- In my `.cabal`, I have a `library`, a `test-suite`, and an `executable`. In the library, there are `other-modules` and `exposed-modules`, both that I need to test using the test suite.
- When I ran `cabal test`, I can't test those in `other-modules` because it is not exposed.

Is there a way to expose these modules only for `test-suite` and no one else?

Comment: I don't think so, the usual practice is to put them under `ModuleName.Private`.

Comment: ^ `ModuleName.Internal` instead of `Private`